# geom_tile plot to visualize missing observations of temporal data

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I'm trying to visualize missing observations in a time series dataset using R.

I have a dataset of the following format with temperature values on 5 different sensors over 15 minute time periods.

```
quarter_hour_readings <- structure(list(sensor_id = c(
  "5a", "5b", "5c", "6a", "6b", "5a",
  "5b", "5c", "6a", "6b"
), date_time = structure(c(
  1573805700,
  1573805700, 1573805700, 1573805700, 1573805700, 1573806600, 1573806600,
  1573806600, 1573806600, 1573806600
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), value = c(
  14.4, 21.8, 15, 19.2, 10, 14.7, 21.1,
  15.8, 18.5, 10.4
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I tried the following code to plot a tile plot of observations of each sensor over time, but an empty plot appears with no error message.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

quarter_hour_readings %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date_time,
             y = sensor_id,
             fill = value)) +
  geom_tile()
```

The following is a similar plot I visualized using Tableau for the same data, where each bar is a sensor and the x-axis represents continuous-time.

[image]

Comment: Hm. Works fine. Maybe restart your R session and run again.